# Finding $f-$invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, applications, jordan-normal-form

How could you know, given a linear application $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$, the $f-$invariant subspaces of arbitrary dimension? For example, let $f:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$ with *associated matrix*:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
How can I know the $f-$invariant planes, and be sure that there's no more?

Is there a systematic way to find them? I'm considering the case that $f$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: You should look at the Jordan block, what are they telling you?

Comment: It's a general question, is case that just computing some products like $(A-\lambda I)X=0$ its gives the solution. In this example, 'looking' at Jordan blocks, I see that the first and second columns are an invariant plane, and the first and fourth columns another, but I'm not sure if there are more.

Comment: By "invariant plane" do you mean a plane where every point is fixed or do you mean a plane $H$ such that $f(H) \subseteq H$?

Comment: $f-$invariant plane, sorry. Yes, $f(H)\subseteq H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is in Jordan form, then it's fairly easy to enumerate all the invariant $n$-dimensional subspaces. That's because the columns $v_1,\dotsc,v_k$ of each Jordan block are a basis for a [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)) of invariant spaces, i.e. (in this case) a sequence of invariant subspaces
$$
V_1 \subset V_2 \subset \dotsc \subset V_k
$$
where each $V_i$ has dimension $i$. Furthermore this flag has the additional property that no subset of $\{v_{i+1},\dotsc,v_j\}$ spans an invariant subspace of dimension less than or equal to $i$.

Thus the invariant planes are exactly those spanned by the first two vectors of each invariant block and those spanned by the first vectors of each pair of different blocks. In your example there are only two such planes:
$$
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I (for example) want to know the $f-$invariant 3-dimensional subspaces, I should look at the first three columns of every block and (if they exist) the first and the two firsts columns of every pair of blocks, did I understand well?

Comment: @iqcd Almost. You should also look at the first column of every triple of blocks (if there are any).

Comment: That's true, I forgot! Thank you for your help!